# what is the difference between MongoDB find and aggregate in below queries?

Tags: mongodb

select records using aggregate:

```js
db.getCollection('stock_records').aggregate(
[
  {
    "$project": {
      "info.created_date": 1,
      "info.store_id": 1,
      "info.store_name": 1,
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "info.store_id": "563dcf3465512285781608802a"
        },
        {
          "info.created_date": {
            $gt: ISODate("2021-07-18T21:07:42.313+00:00")
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

select records using find:

```js
db.getCollection('stock_records').find(
{
 'info.store_id':'563dcf3465512285781608802a',
 'info.created_date':{ $gt:ISODate('2021-07-18T21:07:42.313+00:00')}
})
```

What is difference between these queries and which is best for select by id and date condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question should be rephrased to "what's the difference between find and aggregate".

Before I dive into that I will say that both commands are similar and will perform generally the same at scale. If you want specific differences is that you did not add a `project` option to your `find` query so it will return the full document.

Regarding which is better, generally speaking unless you need a specific aggregation operator it's best to use `find` instead, it performs better

Now why is the aggregation framework performance "worse"? it's simple. it just does "more".

Any pipeline stage needs aggregation to fetch the BSON for the document then convert them to internal objects in the pipeline for processing - then at the end of the pipeline they are converted back to BSON and sent to the client.

This, especially for large queries has a very significant overhead compared to a find where the BSON is just sent back to the client.

Because of this, if you could execute your aggregation as a find query, you should.

Comment: Okay Thanks. It is helpful comment

Comment: is it possible to explain the does "more", because i have this question also, you said that they are converted to internal objects, but find doesn't do the same? how to filter a document without doing that? (assuming there is not index)

Answer (score 1):

**Aggregation is slower than find.**

- **In your example, Aggregation**

In the first stage, you are returning all the documents with projected fields

> For example, if your collection has 1000 documents, you are returning all 1000 documents each having specified projection fields. This will impact the performance of your query.

Now in the second stage, You are filtering the documents that match the query filter.

> For example, out of 1000 documents from the stage 1 you select only few documents

- **In your example, find**

First, you are filtering the documents that match the query filter.

> For example, if your collection has 1000 documents, you are returning only the documents that match the query condition.

Here You did not specify the fields to return in the documents that match the query filter. Therefore the returned documents will have all fields.

### You can use projection in find, instead of using aggregation

```
db.getCollection('stock_records').find(
{
  'info.store_id': '563dcf3465512285781608802a',
  'info.created_date': { 
    $gt: ISODate('2021-07-18T21:07:42.313+00:00')
  }
},
{
  "info.created_date": 1,
  "info.store_id": 1,
  "info.store_name": 1,
  "_id": 1
}
)
```

Comment: Okay Thanks. It is helpful comment

Comment: This is not accurate as Mongo has pipeline optimizations, in this case the `$match` stage will be executed prior to the `$project` stage even though the order is reversed in code. I recommend reading more here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/